# Can I create my own custom Attachment Display Setting?

Tags: customization, media-library

I'm porting a client site over to WP from an old customized .Net CMS and something their existing system does well is the site admin interface contains a simple utility for uploading media to the server and format it automatically for the page so visitors can download the file. (Where file downloads appear in their site there's a special icon and it adds the file size after the anchor text)

It would be a very successful migration for me if I could provide a similar solution in WP from within the Media Library, and extending the Attachment Display Settings with one additional custom option would seem to do it nicely.

- Is this possible? Can I add an option to the Attachment Display Setting menu?
- Can it be done so that it won't be overwritten when WP updates?

I'm glad to figure things out myself although I'm not the best PHP guy. But any clues on where to start would be a tremendous help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size